# PHP newbie, how to send data on new page?

Tags: php, get

I'm learning PHP and I need help to "send" informations on an another page.
I read a text file and I put data on 2 arrays :

```
    $nomVille;
    $nomFichier;

    $index; // index is use for arrays
```

Now I want to build a drop-down list and a submit button.

The drop-down list : show all items on $nomVille

The button : open "villes.php"

villes.php will have to retrieve $nomFichier and $index but I'm not able to do that.

Here is a part of my code :

```
      echo 'Make your choice : ';
      echo "<select name='ville'>";
      foreach($nomVille as $option){
          echo "<option value='{$option}'>{$option}</option>";   
      }
      echo "</select>";
      echo '<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="villes.php">';
      echo '<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Display">';
      echo '</FORM>';
```

Is that correct ?

Comment: send information means?do you want state maintain?use session, get or post method to maintain state. If you just need value of array from other file, like database details, which can be used for all files, you can use include, require, include_once, require_once, etc functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: html get method, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string post is similar, in simple language, there r 2 differences, large data can't be sent by get method (like image upload not possible by get) and get method is visible and stored in cache of browser (sent by header url ). so sensitive data should be sent by post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not got your select element wrapped in form tags which will prevent it being sent. What you actually want is this:

```
echo '<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="villes.php">';
echo 'Make your choice : ';
echo "<select name='ville'>";
foreach($nomVille as $option){
    echo "<option value='{$option}'>{$option}</option>";   
}
echo "</select>";
echo '<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Display">';
echo '</FORM>';
```

On the page "villes.php", you should then be able to refer to the variable $_POST["ville"] which will contain the selected option in the select.

```
echo $_POST["ville"];
```

In order to transfer the values of $nomFichier and $index, you want to send them as hidden elements as part of the form, so add the lines:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='nomFichier' value='".$nomFichier."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='index' value='".$index."'>";
```

Which will again, be able to be grabbed from the $_POST array.

Answer (score 1):

Moving your select into the FORM element will allow the application to post the data on submit.

```
echo 'Make your choice : ';
echo '<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="villes.php">';
echo "<select name='ville'>";
foreach($nomVille as $option){
    echo "<option value='{$option}'>{$option}</option>";   
}
echo "</select>";
echo '<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Display">';
echo '</FORM>';
```

From the `villes.php` page you then have data retrievable in the data that you can access like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['ville'])) {
  $someVar = $_POST['ville'];
}
```

You'll find it worth your time to Google "PHP form tutorial" and seeing how things work from there.